# Why doe \setlist{nosep} not work in the acronym package?

Tags: enumitem, acronyms

Since the `acronym` package is built with the description environment, and the description environment works with Enumitem `\setlist{nosep}`, why is the Acronym package not affected by this command? I needed to reset the `AC@deflist` environment to have a similar effect, which is a much more complex solution than a simple command. Is it possible to configure Acronym to react to the `\setlist{nosep}` command?

```latex
\renewenvironment{AC@deflist}[1]{
    \ifAC@nolist%
    \else%
    \raggedright\begin{list}{}{
        \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\AC@makelabel{\aclabelfont{#1}}}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\AC@makelabel}
    }
    \fi
}{
    \ifAC@nolist%
    \else%
    \end{list}%
    \fi
}
```

Comment: as your own code snippet shows, acronym does not use description but the general list command and that is not changed by enumitem.

Comment: You may want to consider using the `acro` package instead. It's default list is a regular description that can be modified using `enumitem`.

Comment: The acro package is very complex and verbose. The acronym package is simpler to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to redefine the `AC@deflist` environment to use description instead of list with the code below. This way the `\setlist{nosep}` command will also be applied to the acronym list.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{AC@deflist}[1]%
{\begin{description}[leftmargin=!, labelwidth=3cm, labelsep=0pt, itemindent=0pt]}%
{\end{description}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}
    \acro{ML}{Machine Learning}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).